# panda tseries convertion not working

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am new to python and I am trying to build Time Series through this. I am trying to convert this csv data into time series, however by the internet and stack research, 'result' should have had

```
 <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>,
```

but my output is not converted time series. Why is it not converting? How do I convert it? Thanks for the help in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
data = pd.read_csv('somedata.csv')
print data.head()
#selecting specific columns by column name
df1 = data[['a','b']]

#converting the data to time series
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='H')
dates #preview
```

results:

```
 DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 01:00:00',
           ...
           '2015-12-31 23:00:00', '2015-12-31 00:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=2161, freq='H')
```

Above is working, however I get error below:
    df1 = Series(df1[:,2], index=dates)

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Series' is not defined
```

After attempting the pd.Series...

```
df1 = pd.Series(df1[:,2], index=dates)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/someid/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1992, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/home/someid/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1999, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/home/someid/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1343, in _get_item_cache
    res = cache.get(item)
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Comment: It looks like your code is working. The return object that you list is a DatetimeIndex object. I don't understand what you think is wrong.

Comment: Its working but...shouldn't it specify class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'?

Comment: @kingledion Maybe this might help:     >>> df1 = Series(df1[:,2], index=dates)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Series' is not defined

Comment: You can find the class of dates with dates.__class__.__name__

Comment: Try `df1 = pd.Series(...` instead of `df1 = Series(...`

Comment: @ayhan Yup...did that too. It didn't worked either.

Comment: @sharp and after you did what ayhan suggested, what was the error?  Don't respond in comments.  Update your post with what you've tried.

Comment: "line 1" seems strange. You need to first import pandas as the code you've shared does (`import pandas as pd`) Then `df1 = pd.Series(..` should not raise a NameError. If it raises a different error, please share that too.

Comment: @ayhan I have updated the question.

Comment: @piRSquared  I have updated the question.

Comment: Which column are you trying to select with `df1[:,2]`?

Comment: @ayhan date column

Comment: You'll have the date column as the index. `df1 = data[['a','b']]` has two columns, `a` and `b`. Are you trying to use one of them as values in your series?

Comment: Yes, a would be the dates column

Answer (score 1):

you do need to have the `pd.Series`.  However, you were also doing something else wrong.  I'm assuming you want to get all rows, 2nd column of df1 and return a `pd.Series` with an index of dates.

#### Solution

```
df1 = pd.Series(df1.iloc[:, 1], index=dates)
```

#### Explanation

`df1.iloc` is used to return the slice of `df1` by row/column postitioning

`[:, 1]` gets all rows, 2nd columns

Also, df1.iloc[:, 1] returns a `pd.Series` and can be passed into the `pd.Series` constructor.